# "Error! Cannot create crash report" and "Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-1015-raspi (aarch64)" when I run apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dkms

When I type a command like `sudo apt-get install vlc` it says this

```
Loading new sysdig-0.26.4 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-1015-raspi
Building initial module for 5.4.0-1015-raspi
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/sysdig-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-1015-raspi (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sysdig/0.26.4/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package sysdig-dkms (--configure):
 installed sysdig-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sysdig-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: add to your question please `dkms status` and `tree /var/lib/dkms/`

Comment: `Cannot create report [...] File exists: '/var/crash/sysdig-dkms.0.crash` is pretty obvious message, did you try to delete that file manually and check again?

Comment: "`Consult /var/lib/dkms/sysdig/0.26.4/build/make.log for more information`" seems pretty clear. We need to see the content of that log, too.

Comment: i removed sysdig-dkms.0.crash and tried to install a program but it still came up with the same errors

Comment: try $`sudo dpkg -a --configure`
then try `sudo apt-get install vlc` again

Comment: it still says the same thing